# Cut rows to new sheet based on values in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have this list of products, and i want to:

1. Create new sheets based on the values on column C, if there's already a sheet with the same name as the cell value don't create a new sheet. (like "Abstract" in my example that already been created for row 2 and doesn't need to created again for row 3)
2. Cut the entire row to the matching sheet.
3. Make sure the first row is copied to all sheets.

[This is a before picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Amb.jpg)

[After Pic #1: new sheets created, nothing left on first sheet except the 1st row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZn3O.jpg)

[After Pic #2: the sheet contains 2 products because there were 2 "Abstract" in column C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55FBP.jpg)

[After Pic #3: the sheet contain 1 product because there was 1 "Plain" in column C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bqzS.jpg)

[After Pic #4: the sheet contain 1 product because there was 1 "Shiny" in column C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOXwe.jpg)

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the job done.

- I Named the first sheet to "Worksheet".
- The code is dynamic, so you need to input 2 values by yourself:

Which range/names that should create the new worksheets:

```
Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("C2:C5") 'Set range that should create the new worksheet list
```

and how many columns you want to copy to the new sheets (it makes it more dynamic than take the whole row)

```
lastcol = Cells(1, "C").Column 'Set how many column that should be copied to new worksheet
```

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub AddNewSheetFromRange2()
Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myrange As Range
Dim lastcol As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim lrow_newsheet As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("C2:C5") 'Set range that should create the new worksheet list
lastcol = Cells(1, "C").Column 'Set how many column that should be copied to new worksheet

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row for range that should create the new worksheet list

i = 1 'Set first index loop to 1

For Each c In myrange.Cells
i = i + 1 'Create index for each loop, used to know which row that should be copied
    'Debug.Print c 'Print which Sheet Name that will be examine
    Set ws = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets(c.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
        If ws Is Nothing Then

        With ThisWorkbook
            Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)) 'Add new sheet after (not before)
            ws.Name = c.Value 'Rename the new sheet
        End With


        Dim WorksheetSheet As Worksheet 'Declare variable for Main worksheet
        Set WorksheetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet") 'Name the Main sheet
        Dim NewSheet As Worksheet 'Declare variable for new worksheet
        Set NewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Name) 'Make all new worksheets dynamic by taking name from range

        'Copy Headers from Main sheet to New Worksheet
        Worksheets("Worksheet").Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Copy
        Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Name).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).PasteSpecial

        'Copy row from Main sheet to New Worksheet
        Worksheets("Worksheet").Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lastcol)).Copy
        Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate
        lrow_newsheet = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Name).Range(Cells(lrow_newsheet, 1), Cells(lrow_newsheet, lastcol)).PasteSpecial

        'Clear row in Main sheet
        Worksheets("Worksheet").Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lastcol)).Clear

        Else

        'If worksheet already exists, then
        'Copy row from Main sheet to existing worksheet with exactly the same name
        Worksheets("Worksheet").Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lastcol)).Copy
        Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate
        lrow_newsheet = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Name).Range(Cells(lrow_newsheet, 1), Cells(lrow_newsheet, lastcol)).PasteSpecial

        'Clear row in Main sheet
        Worksheets("Worksheet").Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lastcol)).Clear

        End If
Next c
End Sub
```

**Visualizing the code in excel** you will have to start with this:

[image]

and the final output will be this (the four rows into individual worksheets, if the name already exists, it will add to the already existing worksheet)

[image]

Comment: I get a Run-time error 1004 on: ws.Name = c.Value 'Rename the new sheet
Method 'Name' of object '_Worksheet' failed

P.S - how did you upload pictures (png flies) to your answers/replies instead of the links I attached when i asked the question

Comment: Do you use valid name? You cant use speical characters... :P

Comment: valid name where? my file looks exactly like yours and what in the pictures :(

Comment: In the list collection, do you have an **empty or blank** cell (example: Abbstract, Abbstract, blank cell, Shiny)? Then you can get that error message.
When you post, there's a little picture, click on it and you can choose a picture from your harddrive to upload.

Comment: my range is C2:C5 on the first sheet: ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C5") it doesn't have black or empty cells it looks exactly like yours.

Comment: What happens if you rename your sheet to "Worksheet".. becuse `Sheets(1)` might not work, unfortunately.

Comment: when I put a name like Sheets("Worksheet") in Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet") it gives me run time error 9, and after that it give me error 1004 i mentioned before

Comment: it worked on the xlsm file from dropbox, but not on my xlsx file

Comment: the code is definitely working :) but do we have an idea why am I getting this errors?

Comment: sure, i'll send you an email! ty

Comment: If you think the question is solved, please mark it as accepted. It shows other people that the question is solved :). Thank you in advance! [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)